# Where can I (safely) get libintl3.dll?

Tags: windows, windows-7, wget, dll

I am having problems running the Windows version of wget on a Windows 7 machine. When I run the command I get this error:

> The program can't start because libintl3.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.

Is there a safe place I can download and register this DLL? I do not consider safe any of the Google results I see when searching for this file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are on Windows 7, you should also take a look at [WGet 2 for PowerShell](http://huddledmasses.org/wget-2-for-powershell/).

The PowerShell version could be a lot more powerful depending on what you want to do with `wget` (and avoids the whole DLL install issue, making it more portable)

Comment: the link doesn't work

Comment: Someone using a 7 year old version of powershell will be disappointed.

Answer (score 10):

Turns out I didn't install the setup file with dependencies from this page:
http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm
("Complete package, except sources")
Doh!

Comment: Or since I don't want a setup (which that "complete package" is), just the .zip dependencies are enough.